# submitting form values in php using ajax request

Tags: prototypejs, unobtrusive-javascript

okay, so I am trying to load a user's information into form fields after the user has finished creating an account. This is sort of a "re-check your personal info" but here his previously entered values are already set. How should I do so using ajax. I want to use the prototype ajax to avoid obtrusive coding.

Again,these are the steps

1.User creates an account on signUp.php

2.He is redirected to edit.php where he checks his personal info which is set by default.

if I do this

```
function setFormData()
{
 new Ajax.requestHTML("edit.php")
 { onSuccess:someFunction()

 });

}
```

then how can I set the form values, like

```
 function someFuncton(ajax)
 {
    $("firstname").value=??
    $("lastname").value=??
    $("country").value=??
 }
```

Comment: I am confused by "redirected to edit.php". If there is a redirect then a whole new page is loaded and you can prefill the input fields without javascript. What is the AJAX for?

Answer (score 0):

you can in the edit.php output an xml, json or string with the values, parse it and use in your someFunction